# embedding a ruby interpreter in browser

Tags: javascript, ruby, interpreter

I have a rails app where I'm trying to allow users to interactively write ruby code, something akin to [rubymonk](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/6-objects/lessons/35-introduction-to-objects). The plan is to a have a textarea where they can write ruby code, with a button which will execute everything they've written. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

First I was looking at RubyJS, but that seems to just allow you to define ruby objects in javascript. It still requires you to be writing JS. 
Opal was another thought, but that seems to only be server side. 
One option would be to send the string of ruby code to the server and execute it with `eval`, but that seems like a security nightmare.

So this all brings me to my final question. Is there any JS library which will take a chunk of code written in ruby (as a string), and compile it into JS and execute it? Or if I've overlooked something, is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Can you post any research you have done on the subject and more importantly what you have already attempted?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question has been asked but in case people are still interested...

> Opal was another thought, but that seems to only be server side. One option would be to send the string of ruby code to the server and execute it with eval, but that seems like a security nightmare.

You can run Opal on the client side just fine!

[Add opal to your site and then use `Opal.compile()` and `Opal.eval()` to run ruby scripts.](https://opalrb.com/docs/guides/v0.9.2/opal_parser.html) What they've essentially done is to run the opal parser through the opal parser leading to a JS version of the parser. You can find a pre-compiled version of opal that includes the parser by dowloading opal-parser.min.js from the site. This should give you access to the `.compile()` and `.eval()` functions.

Here is the simplest complete online ruby compiler I could come uo with. Note that `puts` prints to the console, so be sure to have something that returns a non-nil value as your last statement if you want to see any output.

### Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Compile ruby from your browser</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Input</h1>
    <textarea id="input" rows="5" cols="50">
puts "Hello, World!"
3 * 5
puts "blurb"
4**6
    </textarea>
    <button id="compile" onclick="compile()">Compile!</button>

    <h1>Transpiled</h1>
    <textarea id="transpiled" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

    <h1>Output</h1>
    <textarea id="output" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

    <script src="js/opal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/opal-parser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">Opal.load('opal-parser')</script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### script.js

```
function compile() {
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  const transpiled = document.getElementById("transpiled");
  const output = document.getElementById("output");

  transpiled.value = Opal.compile(input.value);
  output.value = eval(transpiled.value);
}

document.onload = function() { compile(); }
```

Comment: Ruby has also been [ported to WebAssembly](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs#ruby), which is supported in most Web browsers nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to be executed client-side, you could use [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/). This is what [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/Ruby) does.

If you want the code to be executed server-side, you could use the Ideone API if you don't want to have to deal with security.

Note: Stack Overflow won't let me post a link to the Ideone API, so here is the URL: `http colon slash slash ideone.com slash api`